# Hosting custom HTML in Google drive

Tags: html, google-drive-api, web-hosting

I have spent hours to trying to host some of my local `HTML` pages with `Google Drive`.

I was following the instructions as given in https://www.ecanarys.com/Blogs/ArticleID/135/How-to-Host-your-Webpages-on-Google-Drive, however without any success.

So far the steps I followed -

1. Created a folder in the Google drive
2. Uploaded all files and folders including the `HTML`, `CSS` and other required files using drag-and-drop facility
3. Changed the sharing option to 'Anyone on the internet with this link can view' attached shanpshot
   [image]
4. Next I go to the required HTML page and click Preview
   [image]
5. As per the instruction, I should get some link to display the page through Browser. However I just see the source-code.

Could you please help me the right way to host my `HTML` page with Google-Drive.

Any pointer will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Why do you want to host your HTML with Google Drive? Have you considered other solutions like [GitHub Pages](https://pages.github.com/)?

Comment: Yes. AFAIK, github dont allow to host multiple HTML pages. I have 4 different HTML pages which share the same CSS and JS files. If Github allows to do so, I am fine to explore that as well.

Comment: If you have all of your code in a repository, you can access all of them using realtivel inks. For example, `username.gthub.io/my-repo/first.html` and `username.github.io/my-repo/second.html`.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The web hosting abilities was deleted from Google Drive.

Please see the following G Suite Blog Post to better understand the issue you are challenged with.
[Deprecating web hosting support in Google Drive](https://gsuiteupdates.googleblog.com/2015/08/deprecating-web-hosting-support-in.html)

But you can use **Github** for hosting a static HTML site.
If you have all files into a repository, you go to setting of this repo

[image]

Then go to the Github Pages section.

[image]

Then select the master branch and directory of **index.html** file and save it. In my case, its root directory.

[image]

After that, you will get a URL in this section.

[image]

For Github hosting, you can follow this [instruction](https://medium.com/@svinkle/publish-and-share-your-own-website-for-free-with-github-2eff049a1cb5).